# Will avocado stay fresh longer if stored in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-method, refrigerator, avocados

Should I store avocado in the refrigerator or will it make no difference for how long they stay fresh?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/89/what-can-i-do-to-help-my-avocados-ripen

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ripening of the avocado is slowed down greatly by refrigeration, so it is usually a good idea to let the avocado ripen fully at room temperature. Once it is ripe, it can be stored in the refrigerator for at least a week. This way, it is ready to use whenever you want it. Fortunately, there is a day or two when the avocado is ripe, but not too ripe, so if you check on it everyday when ripening, you will be able to save it at the correct ripeness without worrying about it too much.

Putting an unripened avocado in the refrigerator may prevent it from ever ripening completely. Once cooled to near freezing (40F in most refrigerators), it seems that some avocados (maybe it depends on the type) don't ripen anymore, even when removed to room temperature.

Comment: We refrigerate a lot of avocados.  They do ripen after being taken out, but they seem to take longer to ripen than avocados which were never chilled.  So be patient.

Answer (score 3):

I store my avocados in my kitchen, uncovered, at room temp until I need them.  It is alright to store an avocado in the fridge if you do not intend to use it right away.  The cold temperature will inhibit the avocado's ripening. It may need a day or so out on your counter to ripen once it has been removed from the fridge.

If it is already perfectly ripe I would use it asap and not store it in the fridge.  Also, if you are making guacamole store it in the fridge with the avocado's seed in the same container, it is supposed oxidize (turn black) less/slower.

Comment: I have never found the "store it with the seed" advice to be true.  And we use a lot of avocados.

Comment: Yep, the "store with the pit" idea is a bit of a myth - it just prevents browning where the pit is touching the avocado instead of air.

Answer (score 2):

You can try freezing them, however I've never tried it personally.

> Ripe fruit can be stored in the refrigerator uncut for two to three days. To store cut fruit, sprinkle it with lemon or lime juice or white vinegar and place in an air-tight container in your refrigerator. If refrigerated guacamole turns brown during storage, discard the top layer.
>
> When you have an abundance of fresh avocados, consider freezing them. Pureed avocados freeze very well and can be used in salads, sandwiches and dips.
>
> - Wash, seed and peel the fruit as described above.
> - Puree the flesh, adding one tablespoon of lemon juice for each two pureed avocados. Pack the puree into an air-tight container, leaving 1 inch of headspace.
> - Seal and label the containers.
> - Freeze and use within four to five months.

Source: [Selecting a California Avocado](http://www.avocado.org/how-to-choose-and-use/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Storing them under cool temperatures works well.

Comment: You're not adding any new information here. How cool temperatures affect avocados has been discussed in greater detail in earlier answers.