# Store avocados for say a month

Tags: storage, avocados

Is there any way to store avocados, so that if I buy them today from the supermarket (green and unripe), in about a month's time, I will have them just ready and ripe to eat?

[I don't think this is a duplicate, I've looked at the other avocado questions and none seem to answer this specific question.]

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: In my case: Avocados happened to be on sale (US$0.59 each, doesn't get much cheaper than that in Michigan, USA where I am), so I decided to stock up.

Comment: Doesn't one of those food saver sealer things work for this? It basically creates a airtight bag with plastic and can store a lot of things for a long period of time

Answer (score 2):

If you buy them hard, and put them in the refrigerator right away, you can probably get a month out of them. After having been refrigerated, they will take longer to ripen at room temperature. So check them two days before you want to use them. If they're still a bit hard, leave them in a paper bag on the counter for twice as long as you would unrefrigerated avocados of the same hardness.

Comment: This other answer [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18917/will-avocado-stay-fresh-longer-if-stored-in-the-refrigerator/18932) suggests that if you store it in the fridge for some time, if you subsequently take it out again, it will perhaps never ripen. Your answer seems to contradict that claim. Care to respond? Thanks.

Comment: @KennyLJ  In my experience, it will ripen, and most likely will actually *be* ripe or close to it after that long in the fridge. I've never actually kept an avocado for that long, but I have refrigerated avocados that had come close to being ripe before I was ready for them, and the ripening afterwards was slowed, but not halted.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure they stop ripening in the fridge, dry the unripe avocados, and vacuum bag them, or place them in tightly closed bags while excluding as much air as possible. Store them like this  for four to five days days if the fridge. Then transfer them into a typical not quite airtight fridge style container. Make sure they stay dry

By restricting their ability to absorb oxygen, the CO<sup>2</sup> they expel will be re-absorbed. This CO<sup>2</sup> "shock treatment" is what is used to sea freight avocados around the world

Be gentle when handling so as not to bruise them. Any bruises will start the ripening process

Buy regular just unripe avocados, that look in good condition, and have not been roughly handled

Most avocados ripen in two to three days after being removed from the fridge, if left sitting in a warm and sunny place